# Get the value of javascript object based on key?

Tags: javascript, json

How we can get the specific key value which is dynamically created, like

car object is dynamic like

```
 var car = {type:"Fiat", model_2017:"500", color:"white"};
 var car = {type:"Fiat", model_2016:"500", color:"white"};
 var car = {type:"Fiat", model_2015:"500", color:"white"};
```

How to get the value of second field, which is dynamic, i'm trying like this but it is giving undefined

```
var model_year=2015;
model_year= "model_"+model_year
car.model_year
```

Comment: what is the expected output? & you have same variable with different content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try accessing with `[]` syntax

```
car[model_year]
```

```js
var car = {type:"Fiat", model_2017:"500", color:"white"};
var car = {type:"Fiat", model_2016:"500", color:"white"};
var car = {type:"Fiat", model_2015:"500", color:"white"};

var model_year=2015;
model_year= "model_"+model_year
console.log(car[model_year])
```

Comment: why you write the unnecessary first two code-lines?

Comment: They make clear that a model _key_ can be accessed programmatically since the "model_" prefix is a string constant and the year is joined from a _variable_.